# How to access a variable from inside an object

Tags: c++

How exactly do you access an outside variable from inside an object with C++? Would you use pointers? What is the correct syntax?

I'm not familiar with pointers so anything said before basically just shoots straight over my head.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to call a function on a second object from within my first one. I'd like to be able to go `foo.bar.SaySomething('Hello!');` where foo is my first object and bar is a reference to my second object, assuming that my second object has a function called 'SaySomething' on it.

Also, why was my post edited?

Comment: So, it is legal to do `foo.SaySomething("Hello!");` as well?

Comment: @muntoo But the grammar's now incorrect! :P If you don't mind, I'll make it even more concise, and fix the grammar to boot. 

And yes, you would be able to call foo.SaySomething().

Comment: In C++, if your code is designed correctly, you probably will not have to use raw pointers. Only if you want to use C and C++ together will you use raw pointers. (Notice: This excludes smart pointers.)

Comment: I could say the same. I don't usually make grammatical errors that obvious. *facepalm* But I digress; how would you recommend designing the code to avoid using raw pointers?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4627/discussion-between-elliot-bonneville-and-muntoo)

Comment: @muntoo: I definitely have to differ with you on the "no raw pointers" mantra.  How do you store a re-assignable non-owning reference to an object which is not dynamically allocated?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley [Sorry for taking so long to reply.] You use dynamically allocated memory with smart pointers. :P (No need to *not* use dynamically allocated memory in this case.) That way, you do not have dangling pointers.

Comment: @muntoo: No need *not* to use dma?  Sure there is.  Maybe it just just doesn't fit your design.  The object you want a reference to is a member of another class that you're not in control of.  Or you don't want the performance hit that dynamic allocation incurs.  Even [Herb Sutter agrees.](http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley He agrees... but only if the object pointed to will still be in scope when your raw pointer goes out of scope. "*If you know another object is going to outlive you and you want to observe it, use a (non-owning) raw pointer.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either store a pointer to `foo` in your object (which means you will have to set it somewhere to the correct foo) or pass a reference of `foo` to the method in your object's class that invokes `SaySomething()`. In the former case you will have to check for a NULL pointer. In the latter no NULL pointers are allowed.

Comment: @Muntoo was very helpful, but this is actually what I ended up doing, so I have to accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Relevant parts from [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4627/discussion-between-elliot-bonneville-and-muntoo):

> [Elliot:] I have a main Map object. I have several 'Item' objects that all need to be able to access the same Map object. I was assuming pointers held the key to this. Was I wrong?
>
> [...]
>
> [Elliot:] My `items` need access to the `Map` object because they need to tell it where they are.
>
> [muntoo:] Oh, well, have `Items` inside the `Map`.
>
> ```
> class Map {
>     std::vector<Item> items;
> };
> ```

Comment: I actually ended up passing in a reference to the object, I didn't manage to make this work for me...

Answer (score 0):

As an overly broad answer, you need to have an addressable context for the variable you're trying to use. What this really means depends on what you're trying to do and where in the code you're trying to do it. Are the variables global, members of another class, statically accessible. Check out [CPlusPlus.com's tutorial on variables](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/) as a general reference if you're getting started and Stroustrup's [Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++](http://www.amazon.ca/Programming-Principles-Practice-Using-C/dp/0321543726) if you're more of a book person.

In response to your clarification, this is modified from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/):

```
int main () {
  CRectangle rect (3,4);
  MyWeirdShape wshapeA;
  cout << "rect area: " << rect.area() << endl;
  cout << "Weird Shape area: " << wshapeA.area() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

We're within the `main()` method of the `CRectangle` class and create a new object of type `MyWeirdShape` and then call `area()` to get its size. If this were a static method we could skip the creation of the new object and just call `MyWeirdShape::area()`.

Comment: I just need to know how to specifically call a function on a single non-global object from within another object. I'm not exactly getting started, I'd just like to know the principles behind pointers, if those are the magic solution. No other languages that I've used have pointers so they're new to me.

Comment: Pointers could certainly be used in a situation like this but they're not really the answer to your question. Check out this if you're just interested in getting familiar with the concepts behind pointers. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: I also recommend cplusplus.com; it is where I learned my so-called 'advanced' C++.

Answer (score 0):

lets say i have 2 classes

```
class apple
{
   public:
       double get_wt();//this returns the wt variable
   private:
       double wt;
}

class fruit
{
    public:
       double get_apple_wt();//this returns the wt variable of an apple object whose memory location is stored in apple_ptr

    private:
       apple *apple_ptr;//points to the memory location of apple object
}
```

in the above case get_apple_wt() would be perfectly valid if you have dynamically allocated apple object :

```
apple_ptr = new apple();
```

is this what you wanted to know?
please do comment!